# SharedPreferences not storing value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hi guys I have got a String I am trying to store in to SharedPreferences:

here is the method I am using to store the string:

global vars:

```
private ArrayList<String> mListEmailAddresses;
```

method:

```
public void setEmailAddressList(String emailAddress){
    emailAddress.replaceAll(",", "");
    mListEmailAddresses.add(emailAddress);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("invitefriends", 0);
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < mListEmailAddresses.size(); i++) {
        str.append(mListEmailAddresses.get(i).toString()).append(",");
    }
    LogUtils.log("emails: " + str.toString());
    String theString = str.toString();
    prefs.edit().putString("emails", theString);
    prefs.edit().commit();

}
```

everytime this method is called the str.toString method is updated with a new email added to the list. for example "email1@gmail.com,email2@yahoo.co.uk,email3@hotmail.co.uk" would be the string that gets formed. the Log shows this string correctly. I then go to put theString under the key "emails" and whenever the view is restarted it is refreshed like so:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("invitefriends", 0);
    String savedString = prefs.getString("emails", "");
    LogUtils.log("saved emails: " + savedString);
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedString, ",");
    mListEmailAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < st.countTokens(); i++) {
        String strEmail = st.nextToken().toString();
         mListEmailAddresses.add(strEmail);
    }
```

The problem is that the Log here shows the saved emails is an empty string. What am I doing wrong? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are making the commit on an other instance of the editor. Try the following code

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("emails", theString);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: See also [this example](http://android.codota.com/scenarios/527f7767da0a4e0f5ea63971/android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor?tag=antelope)